# SVGs with filters appear fuzzy on iOS (in <img> tags)

Tags: ios, svg, mobile-safari, svg-filters

I've been experimenting with SVG filters, but can't figure out how to fix this: I have an SVG that uses filter effects like `feBlend`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="70 0 360 360">
  <defs>
    <path id="orange" d="M200,50 a35 35 0 0 1 100 0 l0 70 a40 40 0 0 1 -100 0 z" fill="rgb(252,170,30)"></path>
    <path id="yellow" transform="rotate(45 250 185)" d="M200,50 a35 35 0 0 1 100 0 l0 70 a35 35 0 0 1 -100 0 z" fill="rgb(242,229,0)">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0 250 180" to="45 250 180" dur="1.5s" additive="replace" fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
    …

    <filter id="blendit">
      <feImage xlink:href="#orange" x="0" y="0" result="1"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#yellow" x="0" y="0" result="2"/>
      …

      <feBlend mode="multiply" in="1" in2="2" result="12"/>
      <feBlend mode="multiply" in="12" in2="3" result="123"/>
      …
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" filter="url(#blendit)"/>
</svg>
```

When included on the page as inline SVG, the graphic displays sharp on an iOS retina screen.

However, if I try to use it as a source for an `<img>` tag:

```
<img src='svg-with-filters.svg'/>
```

The graphic appears fuzzy, as if it was an @1x resource on the retina screen.

How do I force the graphic to appear sharp on iOS, without resorting to inline SVG or an `<object>` tag? It renders correctly on desktop Chrome and on Android devices.

### Example

Here's a [CodePen that demonstrates the problem](http://codepen.io/elstgav/full/QbVzqy/), and a screenshot below.

[image: fuzzy SVG rendering]

Comment: Is there a reason against using an object tag? Seems to work with that.